# Graph isomorphism with constraints on the edges using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx, isomorphism

I would like to define my own isomorphism of two graphs. I want to check if two graphs are isomorphic given that each edge has some attribute --- basically the order of placing each edge. I wonder if one can use the method:

```
networkx.is_isomorphic(G1,G2, edge_match=some_callable)
```

somehow by defining function `some_callable()`.

For example, the following graphs are isomorphic, because you can relabel the nodes to obtain one from another.

### [image: G1][image: G2]

Namely, relabel [2<->3].

But, the following graphs are not isomorphic.

[image: G3][image: G4]

There is no way to obtain one from another by re-labeling the nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.  This is exactly what the `edge_match` option is for doing.  I'll create 3 graphs the first two are isomorphic (even though the weights have different names --- I've set the comparison function to account for that).  The third is not isomorphic.

```
import networkx as nx
G1 = nx.Graph()
G1.add_weighted_edges_from([(0,1,0), (0,2,1), (0,3,2)], weight = 'aardvark')
G2 = nx.Graph()
G2.add_weighted_edges_from([(0,1,0), (0,2,2), (0,3,1)], weight = 'baboon')
G3 = nx.Graph()
G3.add_weighted_edges_from([(0,1,0), (0,2,2), (0,3,2)], weight = 'baboon')

def comparison(D1, D2):    
    #for an edge u,v in first graph and x,y in second graph
    #this tests if the attribute 'aardvark' of edge u,v is the 
    #same as the attribute 'baboon' of edge x,y.

    return D1['aardvark'] == D2['baboon']

nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G2, edge_match = comparison)
> True
nx.is_isomorphic(G1, G3, edge_match = comparison)
> False
```

Comment: Thanks, @Joel  that is indeed the case. I got a trouble in defining the comparison function since I was using MultiGraph.

Answer (score 0):

Here answer the problem specifically in the question, with the very same graphs. Note that I'm using the networkx.MultiGraph and consider some 'ordering' in placing those edges.

```
import networkx as nx

G1,G2,G3,G4=nx.MultiGraph(),nx.MultiGraph(),nx.MultiGraph(),nx.MultiGraph()

G1.add_weighted_edges_from([(0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 1), (0, 3, 2)], weight='ordering')
G2.add_weighted_edges_from([(0, 1, 0), (0, 3, 1), (0, 2, 2)], weight='ordering')                                                                            
G3.add_weighted_edges_from([(0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (2, 3, 2)], weight='ordering')
G4.add_weighted_edges_from([(0, 1, 0), (2, 3, 1), (0, 1, 2)], weight='ordering')

def comparison(D1,D2):
    return D1[0]['ordering'] == D2[0]['ordering']

nx.is_isomorphic(G1,G2, edge_match=comparison)                                                                                          
>True

nx.is_isomorphic(G3,G4, edge_match=comparison)                                                                                          
>False
```